# Are Mongoose embedded doc ids supposed to be unique across parent docs?

Tags: mongoose

I have a Mongoose (3.6.1) schema with an array of embedded documents:

```
var document = new Schema({
    name: String,
    fileName: String,
    createDate: Default 
});
var transactionSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    documents:[document]
});
```

When I create new transactions using the transaction schema and then add documents using push(), the document ids associated with the embedded documents are identical in other transactions. That may not be a problem except I'm storing the content of the documents in gridFS and using the embedded document id as a unique key.

Is there a way to get Mongoose to generate system unique ids?

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears that Moongoose does not create GUIDs for embedded documents, I tackled this from another angle. I realized that gridfs-stream created _ids for the files when they were stored. I stored these _ids in my embedded document object so the file associated with the embedded document could be streamed back to the user.